# How can I have an image that changes every 5 seconds in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import aa from '../imgs/aa.png'
import aa2 from '../imgs/aa2.JPG'
import aa3 from '../imgs/aa3.JPG'
import aa4 from '../imgs/aa4.JPG'



import './AnimatedGalery.css'



export default function () {

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have no idea how to start with this. I basically want an image (that I can resize and give css properties) that changes every 5 seconds to another one of those 4 imported images I have here.

Comment: Use state and a setinterval which updates that state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea: put all imported images in a list. Have a state variable for the current image that should be displayed. Set an intervall that executes every 5 seconds in a useEffect that sets the new state with a randomly picked image.

```
const images = [aa, aa2, aa3, aa4];

export default function ImageSwapper() {
    const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setCurrentImage(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]);
        }, 5000)
        
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={currentImage} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you want to have a rotation of your images, then I would just save the currentIndex and display its image:

```
const images = [aa, aa2, aa3, aa4];

export default function ImageSwapper() {
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if(currentIndex === images.length - 1) {
                setCurrentIndex(0);
            } 
            else {
                 setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
            }
        }, 5000)
        
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={images[currentIndex]} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried your second piece of code, because I understand that one the best, but when I load the page, the pictures aren't visible

Comment: I accidentally misspelled the `<img />` tag. Try again

Comment: I works like a charm! Thankyou! Now I understand how you can change the value of an html tag externally in react.

Comment: Great to hear. I am glad you learned something new.

Comment: I added 4 pictures to the images list in total, but it only goes to the second image and stops there. It doesn't change any further. Any way I can fix that?

Comment: nvm! made it work! just had to replace a few bits here and there

Comment: @LarsLagauw Could you share which "few bits here and there" you changed? facing the same issue

Comment: @Kahalon I solved the problem putting currentIndex inside the [], at the end of useEffect

Answer (score 0):

you can add all the images name in a array like this :-

const temp =[aa,aa2,aa3,aa4]

```
const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

setInterval(function(){
 
counter === 4 ? setCounter(0) : setCounter(counter + 1);

 }, 5000);
```

**In  tag you can use it like this**

```
<img src=`{temp[counter]}` />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to get current image, and use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to change image every five seconds, which you can define inside [`useEffect` when the component renders](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects):

```
const getPicture = index => {
  switch (index) {
    case 1:
      return "'../imgs/aa.png";

    case 2:
      ...
    default:
      break;
  }
};

const NUMBER_OF_PICTURES = 4;

export default function Menu() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex(prevIndex => (index == NUMBER_OF_PICTURES ? 0 : prevIndex + 1));
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      /* cleanup */
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  /* on component render*/
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <img src={getPicture(index)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I wish I understood what all that code does. I think this code is to advanced for my demand.

Comment: This is perfectly fine code for you in this example i think. I will explain it you you. Which part of code you do not understand.